# Github Workflows: Changing or specifying environment variables in matrix jobs

Tags: yaml, github-actions

How do I specify or change an environment variable as part of a job matrix?

For example, here I want my job to echo "Two" and "Three" instead of "One", but github completely ignores the definition or change of the environment variable in the matrix:

```
name: test-test-test

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main, develop ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main, develop ]

env:
  MY_VAR: One

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        include:
          - env:
              MY_VAR: Two
          - env:
              MY_VAR: Three
    steps:
      - run: echo "$MY_VAR2"
```

yields `echo "One"` and `echo "One"` in both jobs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this context to access information about environment variables that have been set in a **workflow**, **step**, or **job**. Note that you cannot use the *env* context in the value of the *id* and *uses* keys within a *step*. An example is `env.env_var`.

GitHub provides extensive documentation about contexts at
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you used won't work for matrix. As stated in the [official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-a-matrix-for-your-jobs):

> The variables that you define become properties in the `matrix` context, and you can reference the property in other areas of your workflow file.

In your case, to access the matrix `env` variable you set in the `include` field list, you would need to use `${{ matrix.env.MY_VAR }}`.

Something like this:

```yaml
env:
  MY_VAR: One

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        include:
          - env:
              MY_VAR: Two
          - env:
              MY_VAR: Three
    steps:
      - run: |
          echo "$MY_VAR" # is equal to ${{ env.MY_VAR }}
          echo ${{ matrix.env.MY_VAR }}
```

This will generate 2 `test` jobs: `test (Two)` and `test (Three)`.

I made a test [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/4173413266) if you want to have a look.

---

**Conclusion:**

Basically, the `env` you set at the workflow level isn't the same `env` set in the matrix strategy, so you can't substitute the value there.

**Alternative**

What you could do eventually (as `@Adam` stated in the other answer) is to set the `env` value at the workflow level for it to work, in the `environment` context. ([Reference in the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#using-the-env-context-to-access-environment-variable-values) + [another workflow example](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/10-environment-workflow.yml)).

Example:

```
env:
  WORKFLOW_VARIABLE: WORKFLOW

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      JOB_VARIABLE: JOB
    steps:
      - name: Example
        env:
          STEP_VARIABLE: STEP
        run: |
          echo "Hello World"
          echo "This is the $WORKFLOW_VARIABLE environment variable"
          echo "This is the $JOB_VARIABLE environment variable"
          echo "This is the $STEP_VARIABLE environment variable"
```

But depending on what you plan to achieve, a matrix strategy you be more efficient.